# Azure B2C callback after user signs up: Basic credentials specified for 'PreUserWriteRestful' are invalid

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, claims, azure-policy

We have B2C tenant. After the user signs up, we want to set some custom claims. For this, we want to trigger azure function. I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector) tutorial.

My signin-up policy looks like this:
[image]

"Validate auth code" is API connection:
[image]

I don't understand what Username and Password to provide? Moreover, I do not understand how can I call azure function since it's secured with AAD like this:
[image]

In the end, I have this error while signing up:

```
Basic credentials specified for 'PreUserWriteRestful' are invalid. Check that the credentials are correct and that access has been granted by the resource.
```

The azure function is very simple (but for sure it's not called):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// API call, that is triggered by a sign-up user flow.
/// </summary>
[FunctionName("ValidateAuthCode")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateAuthCode(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ClaimsPrincipal principal, ILogger log)
{
     foreach (var c in principal.Claims)
     {
        log.LogInformation($"Claim type: {c.Type} ; claim value: {c.Value}");
     }

     return new OkObjectResult(new { version = "1.0.0", action = "ShowBlockPage", userMessage = "Auth code issue." });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Username and Password is reference Basic Authentication via a REST call.

> "Basic secures the REST API with HTTP basic authentication. Only
> verified users, including Azure AD B2C, can access your API. The
> username and password are stored in Azure AD B2C policy keys. Learn
> how to [secure your RESTful services by using HTTP basic
> authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api#http-basic-authentication)."
> [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro)

The information above is talking about custom policies but it's protocol specific so it's still relevant to user flows.

Azure Functions supports different type of programming language - but in general you need to look up a sample for the HTTP basic auth for a Web API. I suggest starting with Microsoft's documentation on Web APIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types?toc=/azure/active-directory-b2c/TOC.json&bc=/azure/active-directory-b2c/bread/toc.json#web-apis

From there, locate a sample for Web API based on what you are using with the Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. We use API management service for all our APIs. The Apis will be imported to API management service through GitHub actions and by default "Subscription Required" was turned on. Turning off helped us fix the issue.